# Окно отображается не по центру WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol

Создано окно Window. В него по дефолту грузится UserControl, когда я по нажатию кнопки меняю один контрол на отображение другого, то оно отображается не по центру. Хотя свойство отображение окна по центру установлено.

Вопрос заключается в том, как при динамической смене UserControl-ов отображать окно опять по центру? Размер Window подгоняется под содержимое UserControl-a.
Сейчас поведение такое: при первом запуске все нормально, как только нажимаю кнопку регистрация, то окно просто расширяется и принимает форму не по центру.

Comment: без картинок и кода трудно сказать. Да и что за UserControl тоже не понятно. если ты создаешь многооконное приложение, то попробуй создавать новое окно с этим параметром

        WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"

Comment: Окно общее, в нем меняются только UserControl в которых идет содержимое. Проблему решил, подписался на событие SizeChanged и в нем переопределял окно. Да и смысл в картинках, вроде подробно все расписал. По поводу нового окна? Я не приветствую такой стиль. Предпочитаю все в одном окне делать пока это возможно. :)

Comment: Покажите ваш код, без него откуда мы узнаем, где у вас ошибка?

Comment: Да ошибки в коде нет. Просто нужно было заного пересчитывать положение окна.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    double screenHeight = SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight;
    double screenWidth = SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth;
    this.Top = (screenHeight - this.ActualHeight) / 2;
    this.Left = (screenWidth - this.ActualWidth) / 2;
}
```

Подписавшись на это событие, рассчитывал позицию окна заново.

Comment: `SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight` наверное не совсем правильно — ведь окно не обязательно на _первичном_ экране?

Comment: Судя по всему, вам нужно глянуть [сюда](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2118993/276994).